# Error When Mapping Display Tablet Pen on Linux Mint: X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)

Tags: linux-mint, multi-monitor, tablet

I have a two monitor setup on my computer. A normal monitor, and a display tablet. I'm trying to map the drawing tablet's pen to just the display tablets monitor so I can Draw with the drawing tablet.

**I used this article to find the correct terminal command to use:**

https://askubuntu.com/questions/839161/limit-a-graphics-tablet-to-one-monitor

**The terminal command I'm using:**

```
xsetwacom set "HID 256c:006d Pen" MapToOutput HDMI-1
```

**The error I get after the command:**

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension) Minor opcode
of failed request:  37 (X_ChangeDeviceProperty) Serial number of
failed request:  26 Current serial number in output stream:  29
```

**OS:** Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon

**Drawing Tablet:** GAOMON PD2200

Even after using that command, the pen is mapped to both displays. Does anyone know why I'm getting that error, and how to fix it? Thanks!